# Python Selenium: WebElement not working at all after Login in website because DOM is updated

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm very new to Selenium and **scraping** in general and I need some help please. I'm trying to automate some of my work through a website that provides data and queries using Selenium.

The problem is that after the Login, the DOM gets refreshed and apparently that disconects my WebElement, as I no longer am able of doing any *find_element*, *get* or any type of function after the login is done. I am even trying to do it manually so that any refresh, wait time load, etc. is not needed because it is under human supervision :(

The same issues happens if instead of doing ***driver.click()*** I use ***driver.submit()***

The code is as following:

```
# import web driver
from selenium import webdriver
import time as time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# specifies the path to the chromedriver.exe
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/user/bin/chromedriver')

# driver.get method() will navigate to a page given by the URL address
driver.get('https://app.dnbhoovers.com/')

# locate email form by_class_name
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')
# send_keys() to simulate key strokes
username.send_keys(username)

#Sleep some time
time.sleep(0.5)

# locate submit button by_class_name
log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('continue-btn')

# .click() to mimic button click
log_in_button.click()


#Wait for some seconds as password loads after clicking the contiunue bottom
#try:
driver = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "password"))
    )
time.sleep(3)


# locate password form by_class_name
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')

time.sleep(0.7)
# send_keys() to simulate key strokes
password.send_keys(password)

#Sleep some time
time.sleep(0.7)

# .click() to mimic button click and Sign in
log_in_button.click()
```

After the login is where everything goes down, and if I try to type the following functions I get these errors (even after waiting for the page to load):

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='search-query']")
StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Or if I even try this simple task I get the following:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get'
```

And this goes on, if I try to refresh or go down with the keyboard I get:

```
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.DOWN).perform()
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'w3c'
```

Even if I add this lines after the *.click()* command to tell the driver to wait for the search input to appear, I get errors

```
# ... previous code...#
log_in_button.click()

#New lines of code
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='search-query']"))
    )

StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Refreshing the browser will not make any difference either.

If I inspect the element of the webiste, after the login the  changes completely and I see some ""<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow>"" also.

I'm really stuck right now so any help is deeply appreciated!

Thanks for your time and for reading this long post! You can have a potato :)

Comment: Are there iframe elements?

Comment: Yes src="javascript:void(0)" title and style

Comment: You may need to switch to iframe. Without html code it is hard to tell.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Check @C. Peck's answer. It is absolutely right.

Comment: Hi, it is right but the driver is still getting disconnected even if I fix that line.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this

```
driver = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "password"))
    )
```

WebDriverWait() returns a WebElement and you don't want to define `driver` as such.

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This is telling you that `driver` is a `WebElement`, which you don't want.

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't work either. If I delete "driver = " to that line I still don't get the StaleElement error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait till it is clickable:

```
elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='search-query']")))
elem.click()
```

Try 2:
If there is a running JQuery try running this script before click:

```
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return jQuery.active') == 0)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! But unfortunately, the error is still the same. There is apparenly no webdriver as I get a TimeoutException. The wait.until code didn't work so I tried with "elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(" and I still didn't get any result. I am also trying to switch iframe but I get AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'switch_to'

Comment: Does new page has a different domain?

Comment: I mean is the first part of page url different?

Comment: The URL is the same but the DOM changes completely

Comment: I added one more option, but without page source it is hard to tell

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to add that comment as well. I tried that one too but unfortunately as I mentioned before, this website apparently is cutting the connection with the driver as I can't perform any command on the driver after clicking login, not only on the website, also on the browser as I can't even load a new tab on the driver. I can't manage to do anything even if I try to manually log in and then start the code